# Flutter rxdart Bloc to Bloc Communication Multiple BLoCs

Tags: flutter, bloc, rxdart

I'm using flutter rxdart. Multiple blocs.
Ex: BlocA, BlocB, BlocC etc...

How to communicate BlocA to BlocB, BlocA to BlocC, BlocB to BlocC etc...

My Project have HomeScreen, SearchScreen, SearchResult Screen. like homebloc, searchBloc, resultBloc

If User Enter Search text Result Screen show the result and HomeScreen also updated upon search Text. Any Solution for this Problem using rxdart?

Thanks